# Get the Number of Rows in Column of a worksheet

Tags: powershell

I have an Excel sheet as follows:

```
Id   Name   Address
-------------------
1    t1     Add1
2           Add2
3
```

I want to get the count of non-empty cells in each column, i.e.:

> Column ID → 3 rows
>   Name → 1 row
>   Address → 2 rows

How do I do this in power shell? I tried various things but they don't seem to work.

I am new to PowerShell. Is there a way to get the number of rows for a column directly?

```
$SheetName = "Sheet1"
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"

$Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($XLSDoc)
$Sheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item($SheetName)
$objRange = $Sheet.UsedRange
$RowCount = $objRange.Rows.Count
$ColumnCount = $objRange.Columns.Count
Write-Host "RowCount:" $RowCount
Write-Host "ColumnCount" $ColumnCount
$Range1 = $Sheet.Range("A1:A5")
$TestCount = $Range1.Rows.Count
Write-Host $TestCount
```

Comment: Could you show what you tried? It may help others get a better idea what part you need help with.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$xl = New-Object -COM "Excel.Application"
$xl.Visible = $true

$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\path\to\your.xlsx")
$ws = $wb.Sheets.Item(1)

$rows = $ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

foreach ( $col in "A", "B", "C" ) {
  $xl.WorksheetFunction.CountIf($ws.Range($col + "1:" + $col + $rows), "<>") - 1
}

$wb.Close()
$xl.Quit()
```