# SAS to count excel observations

Tags: excel, sas, vba

I have to carry out a reconciliation of accounts for a number of excel files approximately 500 excel files.

I don’t need to match accounts numbers just the volume by file.

```
Example file 1: \\directory\Loaded\Jan2014\excel1

Example file 2: \\directory\Loaded\Feb2014\excel2

Example file 3: \\directory\Loaded\Feb2014\excel3
```

(account number is always populated in column  B with rows 1 to 5 as the titles)

Required output using above example:

Main Folder (File) | Sub Folder (Jan2014) | File Name (excel1) | count of account numbers

Is this possible using SAS?

So if this is not enough information, i have searched the net and found ways using batch files to bring back a list of files but nothing that counts the observations.

Comment: I think and easier way might be to use a wildcard with SAS import, but for that can i get the file name to be imported?

Comment: Do you have ACCESS to PC FILES licensed (ie, can you do proc import from excel)?

Comment: Also, is the sheet always named the same thing (like, SHEET1) or does it vary?  Is it predicable?

Comment: Yes i can do proc import and all files are named different that why i thought of using a wildcard, but they are also in sub directories. i.e Jan 2014 will have 5 excel files and Feb 2014 may have 100 ect

Comment: Are the sheets inside the files named differently, though, or are they all Sheet1 or whatever?  (File/Workbook = a .xlsx file.  Sheet = the tabs inside a workbook.)

Comment: I can put all the excel sheets into one folder for ease, but they all have different file and different tab names.

Answer (score 1):

The SAS solution is something like this.  You could make this a bit more efficient if you did all of the libnames and then set all of the datasets, but this code is a bit easier, and for 500 I think it's reasonable.  Unfortunately excel libnames don't seem to do rowcounts for you, so you can't just use dictionary.tables to do this.

If the sheet names vary, you will need to modify this to take that into account, either by setting up a macro variable that holds what the sheet name should be if it's linked to the filename in some way, or by having the macro do a query to dictionary.tables to see what tables are present in the libname.

```
%let basedir=c:\temp;  *whatever the base directory is that all of your excel files are upstream from;
filename dirl pipe "dir /b/s &basedir.\*.xlsx";

data libnames;
infile dirl lrecl=1024 pad;
input
@1 filename $1024.;
run;

%macro get_rowcount(file=);
  libname _temp excel "&file.";
  data _rowcount;
  set _temp."Sheet1$"n end=eof;
  length file_name $1024;
  retain file_name "&file.";
  if eof then do;
    rowcount=_n_;
    output;
  end;
  keep rowcount file_name;
  run;

  proc append base=rowcounts data=_rowcount force;
  run;
%mend get_rowcount;

proc sql;
select cats('%get_rowcount(file=',filename,')') into :sheetlist separated by ' '
  from libnames;
quit;
&sheetlist.;
```

Comment: Joe - can you list any module dependencies that this requires to work? Thanks

Comment: This would work in a Windows desktop environment with ACCESS to PC FILES licensed.  In a Windows server environment, this might still work if your administrator has enabled `XCMD`.  In a non-Windows environment, the concept should still be practicable, subject to modifying the directory command for the appropriate system command (so, in Linux, `ls` with appropriate flags), subject again to `XCMD` being allowed if it is a server environment, and subject to having a PC Files Server (and modifying the libname to using that method).

Comment: I've now put all the .xls files in one folder and run a proc import using *.xls as a wildcard. While this works for the first part, i also need to add into the file name in to table created using the proc import. Is this possible?

Comment: You just need to parse the full path file name, which is in that table.  You can do that with a number of ways - use `SCAN` (hint: `-1` in the word column means 'start from the right), use regular expressions, find and substring, whatever you feel most comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Powershell for this, unless you really need to do it in SAS.
To get the result to SAS, if needed, you can save data from powershell to excel file and import it to SAS.

Have a look at e.g. [Get the Number of Rows in Column of a worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937788/get-the-number-of-rows-in-column-of-a-worksheet) as a starter.

Comment: I have never used Powershell, looking at the link above i would have to do 1 file at a time, which is not possible with over 500+ files

Comment: A skilled PowerShell user could write the script such that it used a directory listing similar to my answer above to run a loop over all of the files.  (I'm not such a user, sorry!)