# Importing multiple files at once

Tags: sas

I have three excel files as:

```
C:\business folder\RPT-325-Loan Fee Waivers\2017 01\new_loans_as_of_20170131.xls
C:\business folder\RPT-325-Loan Fee Waivers\2016 12\new_loans_as_of_20161231.xls
C:\business folder\RPT-325-Loan Fee Waivers\2016 11\new_loan_as_of_20161130.xls
```

I need to count the number of observations in these three files. Is it possible to count the number of obs without importing it in SAS?

Also, if we really need to import the file then how can we import these three files together. In the file name 2017 and 2016 is the year name; 01,12 and 11 are the month names and 31 and 30 are the month end dates.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe break this into two questions? (1) how to get a row count without importing, and (2) how to import the files together given the naming convention? And have the title reflect those Q's... "importing multiple files at once" is already reflected in various Q's on this site

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, excel files do not have their observations counted when connecting them with the LIBNAME engines (either XLS/X or EXCEL).  So I think you will have to import them if you want to do this in SAS.

You could either run three PROC IMPORT steps, or three LIBNAME statements, and then perform your analysis that way. There's really no faster way; you of course could write a macro and execute that three times, and have it calculate your names (given month dates etc.), but honestly that seems like overkill unless this is a production system.

If it is a production system, look at [this macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22990171/1056935) on a similar question (h/t Snorehorse for reminding me about it).

Comment: Here's a 2014 example of a macro getting row counts from multiple Excel files: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22990171/1056935

Comment: I'll add that to the answer - didn't remember that answer!